# Does MySQL or SQLite support 'INSERT OR UPDATE' Statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, merge

The "INSERT OR UPDATE" statements are available in Oracle if i am not wrong. The possibility to create a new row if the primary key doesn't exists or update that row otherwise. Or is it only possible using some Stored Procedure or Stored Function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

For SQLite, you would use ON CONFLICT REPLACE

[image: onconflict] - See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

> REPLACE  When a UNIQUE constraint
>   violation occurs, the REPLACE
>   algorithm deletes pre-existing rows
>   that are causing the constraint
>   violation prior to inserting or
>   updating the current row and the
>   command continues executing normally.
>   If a NOT NULL constraint violation
>   occurs, the REPLACE conflict
>   resolution replaces the NULL value
>   with he default value for that column,
>   or if the column has no default value,
>   then the ABORT algorithm is used. If a
>   CHECK constraint violation occurs, the
>   REPLACE conflict resolution algorithm
>   always works like ABORT.
>
> When the REPLACE conflict resolution
>   strategy deletes rows in order to
>   satisfy a constraint, delete triggers
>   fire if and only if recursive triggers
>   are enabled.
>
> The update hook is not invoked for
>   rows that are deleted by the REPLACE
>   conflict resolution strategy. Nor does
>   REPLACE increment the change counter.
>   The exceptional behaviors defined in
>   this paragraph might change in a
>   future release.

Comment: Can you make me an example? Maybe I don't understand. When it finds a conflict it always make a delete->insert or it consider make an update? When will it make (if so) only an update?